# Looping through 'Brush'

Tags: vb.net

I want to get all of the Brushes, this is basically pseudocode which will explain what I'm trying to do:

```
For Each B in Brushes
   'Something with Brushes
End For
```

Brushes is a type though so how would I be able to do that?

Comment: add all brushes to a list and loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using reflection:

```
Dim brushes = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor)) _
    .Cast(Of KnownColor)() _
    .Where(Function(k) k >= KnownColor.Transparent AndAlso k < KnownColor.ButtonFace) _ '//Exclude system colors
    .Select(Function(k) New SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(k)))
```

**Edit** (from Thomas comment)

To get color names (used for brushes)

```
Dim brushColorNames = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor)) _
    .Cast(Of KnownColor)() _
    .Where(Function(k) k >= KnownColor.Transparent AndAlso k < KnownColor.ButtonFace) _ '//Exclude system colors
    .Select(Function(k) k.ToString())
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you do this?

```
dim brush as new Brush() 'needs a proper brush instance, not sure where there is one, so this line won't work
Dim type As Type = GetType(System.Drawing.Brushes)
Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static)
For Each [property] As PropertyInfo In properties
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", [property].Name, [property].GetValue(brush, Nothing))
Next
```

Comment: you'll need to import System.Reflection

Comment: Needs to be `type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static or BindingFlags.Public)` else wont return anything

Comment: I think in this case you should call GetValue with Nothing in both parameters. You aren't getting the value from the brush you created.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do with the Brushes.

```
For Each b in GetType(Brushes).GetProperties
  Dim colorName = b.Name ' If you want color names (AliceBlue through YellowGreen)
  Dim brushValue = b.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing) ' Gives you a Brush
  Dim brushColor = brushValue.Color ' Gives you the hex color of the brush (AliceBlue = #FFF0F8FF)
Next
```

Comment: @Thomas If color is what you want you should enumerate the color enum not the brushes, check my answer.

Comment: I need brushes, I was referring to his variable name colorName :)

Comment: @Thomas you only need the colorName from the brush?